# Umbraco vs DotNetNuke : can't decide which one is more suitable

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, dotnetnuke, umbraco

Imagine 3-4 different domains (like `somesite.co.uk`, `somesite.com`, `somesite.com.sg`) and each one of them will support different languages under them. The number of pages and type of content will be same on all of them (only the content will differ).

So along with the contents, user will need to specify zone and language. (we may need to edit the CMS backend with some of our controls as well).

We can't decide which .NET CMS will suit our need.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would ask in the Umbraco forums on the our.umbraco.org site how one would go about setting this scenario up.

Comment: @BeaverProj: Yes. I should try that as well. SO is 1st thing that comes to mind while asking a question..but in this case their forums maybe a better choice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umbraco will handle this situation quite well - you would create a new node in your content tree for each language, and then assign the domain to it through the node's properties.

This situation is relatively common in Umbraco - I recently launched a six-country, 8-language site (a total of 19 different country/lang combinations), with mappings from existing Belgium domains to the new site structure, without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for clearing our doubts on the 1st part. But we dont want to expose the entire umbraco backend to our users for editing contents. We may need to "restrict" their editing and customize it so that when they are providing the contents, they can specify the language/zone it belongs it. Sort of like a custom form for editing contents. Any pointers if thats possible/feasible in umbraco?

Comment: Absolutely. When creating back-end users you can specify which node they "start" at in the content tree (so you can restrict them to a single node of the content tree, and all child nodes), along with full create/edit/publish permissions. You can also remove access entirely to sections that contain developer or sysadmin functionality too.

Comment: any resources you can recommend for multilingual and multidomain setup?

Comment: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/running-multiple-websites-on-one-umbraco-installation should get you started, and some of the knowledge and principles from http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/running-multi-lingual-sites-under-a-single-domain should help too.

Comment: Thanks codegecko..I was able to setup a multi-domain, multi-language. But not sure if its correct! nonetheless its working. I am now able to map site.uk/en-us, site.uk/fr, site.au/en-us an so on..I just hope it works as we move along :)

Answer (score 7):

I think either will probably meet your needs; I work with DotNetNuke every day, so I can confidently say that DNN can handle anything you want to throw at it.  I'm not as familiar with Umbraco, but your requirements don't sound like there would be anything to exclude a general-purpose CMS (you may also want to investigate [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/)).

So far as DotNetNuke goes, the ability to have multiple, related sites is one of the core concepts.  You can also have one site that displays different content for different languages (I wasn't clear if that the main dividing line between your domains or not).

The development of custom extensions will be done in WebForms if you're using DotNetNuke, which may be a plus or a minus.  If that's a minus, there's also a service framework in the newest versions, which enables a web service development approach that mostly ignores WebForms (using knockout.js or a similar library to present a rich interface entirely on the client).

Answer (score 1):

When I've done a similar analysis I've made a list of requirements, subdivided then into high, medium and low priority before comparing them to a shortlist.  Building the shortlist is key; and usually if you have enough requirements an ideal candidate will emerge.

The WaterAndStone annual analysis of the CMS market is worth reading to make sure that your shortlist is a good one (and that the CMS you will use has a good future) http://www.waterandstone.com/book/2011-open-source-cms-market-share-report

Please be aware that all 'free' CMSs make some money either in support, features, training or add-ons - be aware that making the right choice could avoid costs - especially if the costs are slanted at an area that you're not interested in.  The only free CMSs that are totally free are ones that have simply not worked out how to make money yet.

DOTNETNUKE is trying to move into a paid license model (http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Products/Compare-Editions.aspx) - although it is still offering a free 'community' edition, there's no guarantee it will always be available.

UMBRACO has always said it will always be free, but commonly used add-ons like Courier, Contour CMSImport cost €99 each or more.

As to your choices, the high level requirements that you've stated should be comfortably covered by most mainstream CMS's - so unless you have other requirements you should pick a CMS with a future and a cost model you are happy with!

Comment: Just wondering if l missed something has there been any suggestion that Dot Net Nuke will withdraw the free community edition?  Been using DNN for many years now not heard anything like that?  Assumed much like MySQL will always have a community edition.  Certainly that's what l read when l see anything from the core team.  Again like MySQL an open source project like DNN, moved to a paid edition also.

Comment: DNN is under an MIT license everything that is in CE can never be taken away.  As an employee of DNN corp. I have NEVER heard anyone even suggest ceasing contributions to CE.  It doesn't make sense, the community is our biggest source of customers and the biggest source of modules that make DNN the vibrant platform that it is.  The world would have to turn on it's head before DNN Corp. stopped contributing to the CE platform.

Comment: @ScottS Is there a press release from DNN stating that the DNN CE will be free now and forever?

Comment: @amelvin, DNN is not doing a good job of making it's commitment to the open source publicly visible.  I couldn't find anything relevant in a public place, I had to ask Shaun Walker to find anything at all.  At the end of this http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/1832/DotNetNuke-Professional-Support.aspx lengthy blog post Shaun commits DNN Corp. to always maintaining the free open source release.  Now that people are thinking about the question, again, expect to see a clearer and easier to find commitment to open source some time soon.

Comment: @ScottS Good work in finding that information.  We've all been bitten by changing business plans so its good to hear that DNN will continue to fight Umbraco in this space - it will keep both products honest.

Comment: @ScottS thank you from me, l did go looking for a web page that l could refer to no joy :-( so thank for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this information](http://humepc.com/blog/umbraco-vs-dotnetnuke/) umbraco is much more complicated system. You can't work with site after the installation. Developers need to make preparation operations.

Dotnetnuke is much more easier. It has BSD Agreement and independent develoeprs can edit all the information.

I prefer DotnetNuke. But Umbraco is also a powerful system. It depends on goals of use.